# How to get a data from one php file and retrieve it in another php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file, get

Raising a three years old question.
[How to get a user id from one php file and retrieve it in another php file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296458/how-to-get-a-user-id-from-one-php-file-and-retrieve-it-in-another-php-file)

From my own experience I tried to get an id from one file to execute it in another to retrieve some data from another website. Whenever the page loads I could see the value in url on my browser but the value is returning empty when I tried to use it. Kindly check below what I have tried and suggest if there is a way I could  do it with javascript or jquery or just do it with only PHP.

a.php

```php
<?php

$aa = b.php;

$bar = 1234;

echo “<a href=$aa?$bar target=new window>”Click here”</a>”;

?>
```

b.php

```php
<?php

$foo = $_GET[$bar];

// this one returns empty. But bar is seen on the url as ?bar
echo $bar;
?>
```

Comment: You've forgot to add the `bar` variable name in url: `echo "<a href=\"$aa?bar=$bar\" target=\"new window\">Click here</a>";` and always enclose tag atributes into double quotes (escape them when needed)

Comment: I didn't know having it inside a variable again was important.

Comment: Yes, it's important, other way you'd had a "variable with no value" (1) or "value assigned to no variable" (2) in your URL. 1) Is the way the browser will parse the URL, 2) Maybe is the user/programmer point of view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How u echo the anchor tag doesn't seems good to me, maybe more like:

```
echo '<a href="'.$aa.'?bar='.$bar.'" target="new window">Click here</a>';
```

You can access the value like:

```
$_GET['bar']
```

And you have to echo `$foo` and not `$bar`.

Comment: Why is it better to concatenate instead of parsing variables using double quotes?

Comment: I've always done like this, and I think in html there's must be "" in attributes, what you can't do if the whole string in double quotes.

Comment: Yes, you can do it just by escaping double quotes: `echo "<a href=\"$aa?bar=$bar\" target=\"new window\">Click here</a>";` I like to parse variables instead of concatenation, but who knows wich method is better?

Comment: Yes you are right. I'm used to concatenation, seems cleaner for me, but it's a matter of taste :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the comments added... This is how it's done...

```
<?php
//a.php

$b_php = "b.php"; //file name
$parm = "?bar="; //parameter
$parm_data = "1234"; //DATA
echo "<a href='$b_php$parm$parm_data' target='_blank'>Click here</a>";
?>

//b.php

<?php 
if(isset($_GET["bar"])){ //check if the variable parameter is set or not
$foo = $_GET["bar"]; // $_GET["$bar"] only works if variable exists in the file
echo $foo; //echo $foo
}else{
echo "Empty!";
}
?>
```

It's returning empty because you are trying to echo Variable `$bar` but it doesn't exist.
Also look in to `GET` & `POST` forms for data from `HTML` or `JS` or `Jquery` to PHP.

Comment: Nice answer, it'd be much better with indentation and, maybe, **1)** Separate codes for a.php and b.php **2)** adding and option and explanation to get the variable using ternary operator.